# Webpack & Babel : Server Side rendering of React Component "Unexpected token '<'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, babeljs

I've been investigating this issue for 3 days now but cannot get it working.

The full error is :

```
C:\Users\XXXXXX\WebstormProjects\XXXX\server\routes\auth.jsx:58
    return res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<LoginPage />));
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XXXXXX\WebstormProjects\XXXX\index.js:10:20)
```

Here is my webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/client/src/app.jsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist/js'),
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: "/"
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: [
                path.join(__dirname, '/client/src'),
                path.join(__dirname, '/server/routes')

        ],
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                babelrc: false,
                presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2', 'react']
            }
        }],
    },

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    watch: true
};
```

Now the /server/routes/auth.jsx file :

```
const express = require('express');
const validator = require('validator');

const router = new express.Router();
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const LoginPage = require('../../client/src/containers/LoginPage.jsx');


function validateLoginForm(payload) {
    const errors = {};
    let isFormValid = true;
    let message = '';

    if (!payload || typeof payload.email !== 'string' || payload.email.trim().length === 0) {
        isFormValid = false;
        errors.email = 'Please provide your email address.';
    }

    if (!payload || typeof payload.password !== 'string' || payload.password.trim().length === 0) {
        isFormValid = false;
        errors.password = 'Please provide your password.';
    }

    if (!payload || typeof payload.password !== 'string' || payload.password.trim().length <= 8)
    {
        isFormValid = false;
        errors.password = 'Please provide a password that\'s more than 8 char';
    }
    if (!isFormValid) {
        message = 'Check the form for errors.';
    }

    return {
        success: isFormValid,
        message,
        errors
    };
}

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log("lol");
    const validationResult = validateLoginForm(req.body);
    if (!validationResult.success) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: validationResult.message,
            errors: validationResult.errors
        });
    }
    console.log("Went through validationResult without problems");
    return res.status(200).end();
});


router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    return res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<LoginPage />)); // THE PROBLEM
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log("lmao")
});


module.exports = router;
```

Finally the /client/src/containers/LoginPage.jsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm.jsx';


class LoginPage extends React.Component{

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     */
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // set the initial component state
        this.state = {
            errors: {},
            user: {
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }
        };

        this.processForm = this.processForm.bind(this);
        this.changeUser = this.changeUser.bind(this);
    }

    /**
     * Process the form.
     *
     * @param {object} event - the JavaScript event object
     */
    processForm(event) {
        // prevent default action. in this case, action is the form submission event
        event.preventDefault();

        const email = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.email);
        const password = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.password);
        const formData = `email=${email}&password=${password}`;

        // create an AJAX request
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', '/login');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                // success

                // change the component-container state
                this.setState({
                    errors: {}
                });

                console.log('The form is valid');
            } else {
                // failure

                // change the component state
                const errors = xhr.response.errors ? xhr.response.errors : {};
                errors.summary = xhr.response.message;

                this.setState({
                    errors
                });
            }
        });

        xhr.send(formData);
    }

    /**
     * Change the user object.
     *
     * @param {object} event - the JavaScript event object
     */
    changeUser(event) {
        const field = event.target.name;
        const user = this.state.user;
        user[field] = event.target.value;

        this.setState({
            user
        });
    }

    /**
     * Render the component.
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <LoginForm
                onSubmit={this.processForm}
                onChange={this.changeUser}
                errors={this.state.errors}
                user={this.state.user}
            />
        );
    }

}

export default LoginPage;
```

I first added the `path.join(__dirname, '/server/routes')` in order to tell Webpack and babel to also search for this folder to transpile jsx, but it fails no matter what.

I then replaced `return res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<LoginPage />));` in auth.jsx by :

```
var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(LoginPage));
return res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString('base', html));
```

but, by doing this, node gives me another error which is :

```
C:\Users\XXXXXX\WebstormProjects\XXXX\client\src\containers\LoginPage.jsx:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XXXXXX\WebstormProjects\XXXX\server\routes\auth.jsx:8:19)
```

which is, again, a transpiling problem.

Note that without that route in auth.jsx, the web App works all fine, except that I can't access /login via URL.

What am I doing wrong ?

I'm using the latest versions of Express, React, React Router and Node. My OS is Windows 7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's the `webpack.config.js` that you are showing, not the `package.json`, isn't it?

Comment: @atomrc ups, corrected. Thanks :)

Comment: might be because .jsx file contains and non-es2015 Code which webpack cant read

Comment: @KrunalLimbad Isn't that Babel's job, to transpile ES6 code to something Webpack can read ?

Comment: yes exactly but, see my comment i said you are giving webpack that isn't ES6 Code

Comment: @KrunalLimbad Thanks for trying to help me out, but atomrc had the right answer. And this had nothing to do with my code. :p

Comment: happy to help , and sorry though for misleading you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I know what is the problem here.

You indeed compile your `jsx` file and your `webpack.config.js` seems perfect (it includes `react` presets, so it should work).

But you are only compiling for the `client` it seems, and you are trying to consume the uncompiled file on the server.

But `node` cannot read `jsx` on its own.

The option I would suggest here, it to allow babel to also compile server side files.

To do that, you can use `babel-cli`.

Simply add this in your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "babel-node index.js --presets es2015,react"
}
```

And start you server like this

`npm start`

Then it should first compile the files with `babel` and start your server.

Here is an example you can inspire from https://github.com/babel/example-node-server

This should fix your problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second part of the code you posted indeed solved the first issue, which was the `Unexpected token <`.
The first part of the code should solve the second issue, `Unexpected token import`, except that I'm new to React and Javascript in general, so I don't know how to get Webpack compile many files at a time. Am I supposed to do what is stated here : 
https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html ?

Comment: I updated my answer. This solution should fix both your problems without changing any bits in any of your source file :)

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but tried to install node-jsx and still the same error but written differently : `Error transforming C:\Users\XXXXXX\WebstormProjects\XXXX\client\src\components\LoginPage.jsx to JS: Error: Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration`, giving me the feeling that the error is provoked by my code but no matter how many times I read it, I can't find where's the error..

Comment: No indeed, this solution didn't take the `import` part into account. My updated answer should fix this

Comment: Yes it did ! I was previously using `nodemon --use_strict index.js` for the `start` script but I guess I'll have to do without it. Now I got another error but it isn't related to this. Many thanks, you saved my day :p
EDIT : Nevermind, didn't click on the link before writing up my comment. Now it works with nodemon and babel-cli :)

Comment: Oh you can still use `nodemon` :) `nodemon --use_stict index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,react` :)